# Navigating between multiple forms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, navigation

I have 2 forms of which one of them has a shockwave component added to it, it plays a flash movie and on click of a button created in flash the form 1 (frmFlashIntro) unloads and form 2(frmMain) starts.
since frmFlashIntro is a form which is used only once i want to unload the form rather than hide it. i also want frmMain to have complete control once frmFlashIntro closes as if it is the main form.
Hiding the form does not seem to be a good way to go about doing this thing.

What i am currently doing is i created a property in frmFlashIntro and added get and set methods to them (both of them are blanK)

```
public Form FormfrmMainRef { get; set; }
```

I added this code to a click event.

```
frmMain fm = new frmMain();
this.FormfrmMainRef = fm;
FormfrmMainRef.Show();
```

now this effectively shows my frmMain but keeps the frmFlashIntro also running so i did this

```
frmFlashIntro fi=new frmFlashIntro();
fi.Close();//checked with dispose also
```

i know i am doing something wrong in the last step. Can anyone please tell me how do i close that form and free the resources held by it.

Also i do not want to use an MDI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like frmMain has no reference to the original frmFlashIntro. Your bit of code

```
frmFlashIntro fi=new frmFlashIntro();
fi.Close();//checked with dispose also
```

will actually create a second frmFlashIntro, so when you call fi.Close() you're actually closing the second form, not the original.

Theoretically you should be able to add a property to your frmMain that's a reference to frmFlashIntro, and then call Dispose on that so something like

frmMain fm = new frmMain();
this.FormfrmMainRef = fm;
fm.FormIntroRef = this;
FormfrmMainRef.Show();

And then in the load event of frmMain, add a call to FormIntroRef.close()

Ok, but, all that aside, I think the best way to solve this problem is to update the Program.cs file and then have something like

```
frmFlashIntro flashIntro = new frmFlashIntro
frmFlashIntro.ShowDialog();
frmMain mainForm = new frmMain()
Application.Run(frmMain);
```

Oh, and a second side note, generally, types begin with capital letters, and instances of those types begin lowercase, and the are camel cased. So you'd normally have something like

```
MainForm frmMain = new MainForm()
```

That should achieve your desired result.

Comment: it says an object reference is required to do this..is it good to create and obj in the program.cs file?? and what if i have many command buttons in the frmMain and each one of them opens a new form. How do i solve that?

Comment: Opening new forms from your mainform is no big deal. Are you having issues with that as well? What error does it give you?

Comment: no there isnt a problem opening forms, the prob is when i Dispose them the program exits. can you tell me how to edit the program.cs with event handlers..e.g if i click on one of the 4 buttons that are there in the main form how do i open new forms on those click events. If you could point me to an article that would also do..but would be better if you could give me some examples pertaining to my quesiton..and thanks..for that reply..i created an object in program.cs and it worked perfectly..i need to control the flow now with click events

Comment: You probably don't want to start putting event handlers in Program.cs(although there isn't any reason why you can't).

Comment: To open new forms, you simply put the following two lines in the event handler ChildForm newForm = new ChildForm(); newForm.Show(); You could also use newForm.ShowDialog() if you need a modal window.

Comment: yes that is true, but then how do i solve the problem of unloading the previous form? because if i hide the previous form then even if the current form is closed the application doesnt exit..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to dispose the form with fi.Dispose() ?

Comment: yes, the frmFlashIntro stays in memory still. That shouldnt be happening right?

Comment: Yes, Dispose is supposed to release every resources used by the form !